# If $S_1, S_2$, and $S_1 \cup S_2$ are $\sigma$-fields, then either $S_1 \subset S_2$ or $S_2 \subset S_1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I wanted to show that

> If $S_1, S_2$, and $S_1 \cup S_2$ are $\sigma$-fields, then either $S_1 \subset S_2$ or $S_2 \subset S_1$.

Here is what I've tried:

Assume the opposite: $S_1 \not\subset S_2$ and $S_2 \not\subset S_1$. Therefore $\exists A \in S_1: A \not\in S_2$ and $\exists B \in S_2: B \not\in S_1$. Consequently $A, B \in S_1 \cup S_2$ but $S_1 \cup S_2$ is a $\sigma$-field so $A \cup B \in S_1 \cup S_2$. Then either $A \cup B \in S_1$ or $A \cup B \in S_2$. Without loss of generality, assume the former. And at this point I wanted to show a contradiction by arriving at $B \in S_1$. Yet it doesn't seem to work.

Any hints are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that because both $A$ and $B$ belongs to $S_1\cup S_2$, then $A\cup B, A\cap B$ and $A\bigtriangleup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ are all in $S_1\cup S_2$ (by properties of a $\sigma$-field.
Then, by the Pigeonhole principle, at least two of these sets should belong to either $S_1$ or $S_2$. Without loss of generality, assume they belong to $S_1$ and note that 
$$
A\cup B= (A\bigtriangleup B)\cup (A\cap B)\\
A\bigtriangleup B= (A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)\\
A\cap B= (A\cup B)\setminus (A\bigtriangleup B)
$$
Then, we have that the three sets belong to $S_1$.

Finally, note that $B\setminus A= (A\cup B)\setminus A$ and that $B= (B\cap A)\cup (B\setminus A)$

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to just consider $A\triangle B$? If $A\triangle B\in S_1$ then $B=A\triangle(A\triangle B)\in S_1$, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's a lot easier. I didn't know about that identity. Thanks

Comment: In fact, the set of all subsets of a set is a group under the operation $\triangle$. In this problem $S_1,S_2,S_1\cup S_2$ are groups, so it's a special case of the fact that a group can't be the union of two proper subgroups.